# Detecting supported interfaces in Flask-Ask Alexa Echo Show

Tags: python, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, flask-ask

I am trying to build a voice skill for both Echo Show [Screen Enabled] and Echo Dot [Audio only]. Apparently the response directives have to be changed depending on the device if not, it would result in "[Alexa having trouble accessing the skill](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/93331/newly-published-skill-sorry-im-having-trouble-acce.html?sort=votes)".

How do we determine the supported interfaces in Flask-ASK ?

```
...
  "context": {
    "System": {
      "application": {
        "applicationId": "<value>"
      },
      "user": {
        "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.<value>"
      },
      "device": {
        "supportedInterfaces": {
          "Display": {},
          "AudioPlayer": {},
          "VideoApp": {}
        }
      }
    }
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
def has_screen():
if context.System.device.supportedInterfaces.Display is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```